# Recovering the original JSON from SwaggerParseResult

Tags: java, json, swagger, openapi

I discovered that `OpenAPIV3Parser` provides methods to deserialize Open API doc JSON, but doesn't allow to serialize it back. If, for example, I need to make a deep copy of `SwaggerParseResult`, I can't serialize it back into a JSON and then create a new `SwaggerParseResult` by deserializing that JSON. In fact, I'm not sure what the official guideline is for recovering the original JSON from `SwaggerParseResult` (suppose I don't store it in memory)

Please note that reserialized JSON should be valid: it should be able to be redeserialized back into `SwaggerParseResult` that returns a valid (non-null and accepted by Swagger UI) `OpenAPI` on `swaggerParseResult.getOpenAPI()` invocation

Are there any workarounds?

Here's what I tried:

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.parser;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class ParserTest {
    private final OpenAPIV3Parser parser = new OpenAPIV3Parser();
    @Test
    void testParser() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String testDoc = getTestDoc();
        SwaggerParseResult parseResult = parser.readContents(testDoc);
        // I tried with and without writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        String reserializedDoc = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(parseResult);
        // doesn't work, OpenApi is null
        SwaggerParseResult redeserializedDoc = parser.readContents(reserializedDoc);
    }

    String getTestDoc() {
        return """
                {
                  "openapi": "3.0.1",
                  "info": {
                    "title": "Hello World API",
                    "version": "1.0"
                  },
                  "servers": [
                    {
                      "url": "http://localhost:8090",
                      "description": "Generated server url"
                    }
                  ],
                  "paths": {
                    "/joy": {
                      "get": {
                        "tags": [
                          "Message Controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "getMessageOfJoy",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "/auth/hello-world": {
                      "get": {
                        "tags": [
                          "Message Controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "getHelloWorld",
                        "parameters": [
                          {
                            "name": "principal",
                            "in": "query",
                            "required": false,
                            "schema": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "/error": {
                      "get": {
                        "tags": [
                          "my-error-controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "error",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "put": {
                        "tags": [
                          "my-error-controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "error_3",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "post": {
                        "tags": [
                          "my-error-controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "error_2",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "delete": {
                        "tags": [
                          "my-error-controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "error_5",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "options": {
                        "tags": [
                          "my-error-controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "error_6",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "head": {
                        "tags": [
                          "my-error-controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "error_1",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "patch": {
                        "tags": [
                          "my-error-controller"
                        ],
                        "operationId": "error_4",
                        "responses": {
                          "200": {
                            "description": "OK",
                            "content": {
                              "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "components": {
                    "schemas": {
                      "SuccessMessage": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "message": {
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "FailureMessage": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "message": {
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          "method": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                              "GET",
                              "HEAD",
                              "POST",
                              "PUT",
                              "PATCH",
                              "DELETE",
                              "OPTIONS",
                              "TRACE"
                            ]
                          },
                          "request_path": {
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                """;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a deep copy? Fine. Here's how you do a deep copy:

```java
    @SneakyThrows
    private OpenAPI deepCopy(OpenAPI openAPI) {
        String serializedOpenApi = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(openAPI);
        return objectMapper.readValue(serializedOpenApi, OpenAPI.class);
    }
```

You can apply this techique to anything whether something is available out-of-the-box or not